# Try! throwing fatal error in Swift 3, issues updating from Swift 2

Tags: swift3, try-catch, xcode8

I am trying to parse the JSON data from my server and I am getting an error when it hits the `try!` statement and it is crashing. It is telling me

> Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0.

It my be because I have not updated my code correctly to Swift 3. I was having an issue with if let parse for the longest time until I switched the as to as?

```
@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text;

    // Check for empty fields
    if((userEmail?.isEmpty)! || (userPassword?.isEmpty)! || (userRepeatPassword?.isEmpty)!){

        //Display alert message

        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required");

        return;
    }

    //Check if passwords matech
    if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword){

        // Display alert message
        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Passwords do not match");
        return;
    }

    // Send user data to server side
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "Post";

    let postString = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)";

    //adding the parameters to request body
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    //creating a task to send the post request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        //parsing the reponse

        //converting response to Any
        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String:Any]

        //parsing JSON
        if let parseJSON = json{
            let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
            print("result: \resultValue)")

            var isUserRegistered:Bool = false;
            if(resultValue=="Success") { isUserRegistered = true;}

            var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["messsage"] as! String;
            if(!isUserRegistered)
            {
                messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String;
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                //Display alert message with confirmation.
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil);
                }

                myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);
            };
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: The json you are trying to parse is invalid! Don't use `try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(...)` - what happens if your sever has a downtime / maintenance / some error which does not produce valid json? Answer: your app will crash :(

Comment: An exclamation mark invites you: *Please crash me!* It's up to you to catch the error. You are using too many exclamation and question marks anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) (specifically, for you, the chapter about `try/try?/try!`).

Comment: I tried dropping the the ! from the try and it throws an error with the let task URL section. I even tried encompassing the whole section in a do statement to catch the error but it doesn't work either.

Comment: "I even tried encompassing the whole section in a do statement" - worst idea EVER. First: you cannot catch these kind of exceptions, secondly: fix your code, dont be that guy and just catch the bugs you are introducing yourself into the code. And PLEASE do some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is that you are sending literal `"Optional(Foo)"` strings to the server via String Interpolation. `userEmail` and `userPassword` will never match and the server sends no data back. In Swift 3 you have to explicitly unwrap even implicit unwrapped optional strings.

The solution is a waterproof error handling with optional bindings

```
@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

   // Check for empty fields
   guard let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text, !userEmail.isEmpty,
       let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text, !userPassword.isEmpty,
       let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text, !userRepeatPassword.isEmpty else {

          //Display alert message
          displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required")
          return
   }
...
```

Now all relevant optionals are safely unwrapped and the server will get the right data.

Further trailing semicolons and parentheses around `if` conditions are not needed in Swift and use `URLRequest` rather than `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift 3

```
var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!) // var is mandatory if properties are going to be changed.
```

PS: In any case – as already mentioned in the comments – **never** use carelessly `try!` when receiving data from a server.